# mysql error#1064 in a simple sql function

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have coded this sql function and am getting 1064 error, i cant spot the error, could you please hellp me out?

> Error Code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`ALN` INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
>       READS SQL DATA
>       BEGIN
>        Declare substat' at line 1

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `substation1`(`subofficecode` INT,`productcat` VARCHAR,`ALN` INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
 DECLARE substation_ID VARCHAR(10);
 DECLARE pcat VARCHAR(2);
 DECLARE  i INT;
 IF (LENGTH(subofficecode) < 3)
 subofficecode=CONCAT("00",subofficecode);
 END IF;

 IF(productcat = "REF")
 pcat="11";
 ELSE IF (productcat = "DF")
 SET pcat="12";
ELSE IF (productcat = "MWO")
 SET pcat="13";
ELSE IF (productcat = "WM")
 SET pcat="14";
ELSE IF (productcat = "SPLIT")
 SET pcat="15";
 ELSE
 SET pcat="16";

 END IF;

 SET i=(SELECT MAX(substationID) FROM Substation) + 1;

 RETURN CONCAT(subofficecode,pcat,ALN,i);     

END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fixing a syntax error. You must specify a length to you `productcat` parameter (e.g. `VARCHAR(10)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the size for the varchar:

```
FUNCTION `substation1`(`subofficecode` INT,`productcat` VARCHAR**(10)**,`ALN` INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
```

Comment: worked! :) though there are more errors apparently near 'set subofficecode=concat('00',subofficecode);
     END IF;
     
     IF(strcmp(' at line 8